# How to format a user input into a different out put?Python

Tags: python

How can from an input (10 number): `XXXXXXXXXX`

convert into : `X.XX.XX.XX.XXXX`

So far this is my code:

```
creat_number_account = input("Account Number:")

def c_n_account(creat_number_account):
    
    if len(creat_number_account) <10:
        print("This account require 10 numbers")
        
    elif n_list[10] == "0":
            print("The last number can't be: '0'")
    else:
        list =[]
        for n in creat_number_account:
            list+= n
        print(f'{list [0]}.{list[1][2]}.'
    f'{list[3][4]}.{list[5][6]}.{list[7][8][9][-1]}')

print(c_n_account(creat_number_account))
```

OUTPUT:

```
print(f'{list [0]}.{list[1][2]}.'
IndexError: string index out of range
```

Comment: Theres no point in making `list` at all, just use the `creat_number_account` and index from that

Comment: `list[1][2]` **does not** mean "`list[1]`, followed by `list[2]`". It means "first do `list[1]`, and then get the `[2]` *from that*".

Comment: X.XX.XX.XX.XXXX -> this is  11 digits.

Comment: @DevangSanghani - Judging from the `[9][-1]`, the op expects the last digit to be repeated

Comment: @Sayse, I have try that way and still string index out of range.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding to  answer by @Sefan, keep prompting the user until the correct format is recevied:

```
n = input("Account Number:")

def c_n_account(n):
    while True:
        if len(n) < 10 or len(n) > 10:
            print("This account requires 10 numbers only")
            n = input("Account Number:")
            continue            
        elif n[9] == "0":
             print("The last number can't be: '0'")
             n = input("Account Number:")
             continue    
        else:
            act = f"{n[0]}.{n[1:3]}.{n[3:5]}.{n[5:7]}.{n[7:]}{n[-1]}"
            return act
            break
        
    

print(c_n_account(n))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `creat_number_account[1:3]` if you want to print more than 1 character from the input string.
Something like this should work for you:

```
creat_number_account = input("Account Number:")

def c_n_account(creat_number_account):
    if len(creat_number_account) <10:
        print("This account require 10 numbers") 
    elif creat_number_account[10] == "0":
        print("The last number can't be: '0'")
    else:
        print(f'{creat_number_account[0]}.{creat_number_account[1:3]}.{creat_number_account[3:5]}.{creat_number_account[5:7]}.{creat_number_account[7:]}')
```

You should add a check if the input is bigger than 10 characters.